# Surround function parameter with single quotes

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote the following function to recursively rename files in some subdirectories:

`rrename(){ find . -type f -name $1 -execdir mv {} $2 ';' }`

This works fine when I call it like this:

`rrename '*.md' renamed.md`

however, I would rather not need to include the single quotes and call it like this instead:

`rrename *.md renamed.md`

I tried this but it still does not work:

`rrename(){ find . -type f -name "'$1'" -execdir mv {} $2 ';' }`

HOw can I fix it?

Comment: (1) [Quote right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). (2) Magic alias, see *Applications* [here](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/aliases.html).

Comment: Are you sure you are posting what did work? I have tested your initial function and command, and I couldn't make it work properly. Please post the actual code that worked. Then just saying "it [still] does not work" is not very helpful: please post the result of the commands. And last, I'm not sure what are trying to do, but 1) why do want to avoid the single quotes? They ensure that no expansion can occur on `*.md`; and 2) if you have several files ending with `.md` in the same directory they will all be both renamed to `renamed.md` (i.e. only one will be kept, the other ones will be lost)

Comment: Your definition of `rrename` is *not* syntactically valid in Bash. It's not the function cannot be used, it cannot be *defined* in the first place. The definition would work in Zsh. Your blatantly unquoted `$1` and `$2` are wrong in Bash, they can be safely left unquoted in Zsh. Despite the `bash` tag, **is your shell Zsh?**

Answer (score 1):

When `*.md` is *unquoted*, the pattern gets expanded **before** the arguments are handed to the function. In that case, `$1` is the first markdown file in the current directory and `$2` is the second one. If you want to pass a *pattern* to a function, you **must** quote it.

Similarly, in the function, when `$1` is *unquoted* it will be expanded (to markdown files in the current directory) before `find` is launched.

Do it this way:

```sh
rrename() { find . -type f -name "$1" -execdir mv {} "$2" ';' }
# ...............................^..^................^..^

rrename '*.md' renamed.md
# ......^....^
```

All those quotes are **necessary**.

---

Tangentially, what happens when there are *multiple* *.md files in a particular directory? All of them are getting renamed to one file.